# Setting RelativeSource correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml, observablecollection

I have a combo box on a xaml form (MainWindow).

I set the Items source to an ObservableCollection in the code behind.  To populate the Combo box I used Relative Source (it sits inside an ItemsControl), which worked great (without it, if did not populate):

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

I have now factored out the ObservableCollection into a seperate View Model Class, named 'MainWindowViewModel', the combo box does not populate.

I have set the DataContext of the MainWindow to my ViewModel and have checked that it populates other controls as expected, which it does.

How should I construct the RelativeSource so the combo box populates?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: I'm not sure you need the RelativeSource at all, the combobox should inherit its data context from the window anyway?

Comment: Thanks jk - yes I thought that too - I think it didn't populate due to it sitting inside an ItemsControl.Template :  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableItems} did not populate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add the Path at the end, thus:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.SelectableItems}"
```

Comment: Try to just use `Path=SelectableItems`

Comment: I'm a relative WPF newbie, but I'm trying to understand RelativeSource better. It seems to me you've told the Item Source to use the same DataContext in use by the parent Window and to use the property named SelectableItems in that context. Since you would inherit that DataContext by default, something in the xaml parent chain you didn't show us must be using a different data context.  I for one learned the proper syntax of Path=DataContext.Property by reading your post so +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to use a `RelativeSource` any longer. If you don't specify a `RelativeSource` (or `Source`, or `ElementName`), then the binding will resolve against the current `DataContext`. Since the `DataContext` is inherited, your `ItemsControl` obtains its `DataContext` from the parent `Window`. Thus, this binding will resolve against your view model.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableItems}"
```